# segmentaion fault on large recursive string manipulation

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb

I am doing the challenge from [www.adventofcode.com/day/10](http://www.adventofcode.com)

I have a code that i think works, I am using c++ just to get to learn while having fun.

I am doing the string manipulation recursive.
The problem here is that the program crashes with segmentation fault
on the line "char ch = line[0]" when doing more than 38 iterations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string count_chars(string line){
    char ch = line[0];
    uint i;
    for(i = 0; ch == line[i]; i++){

    }
    if(i != line.length()){
        line = to_string(i) + ch + count_chars(line.substr(i));
    }
    else{
        line = to_string(i) + ch;
    }
    return line;
}
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    //ifstream in("dayx");
    /*
    if(argc ==1)
        return 1;
    string line;
    cout << line.capacity() << endl;
    line = args[1];
    */
    string line = "1";
    for(int i = 1; i < 40; i++){
        line = count_chars(line);
        //cout << line << " after " << i << " iterations" << endl;
        cout <<"Line size: " << line.size() << endl;
    }
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

The code is compiled using:

```
g++ day10.cpp --std=c++11 -g
```

My questions, why is this happening, how can i prevent it and how can i use gdb to figure this out? Thanks!

I am using linux and gcc 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stack overflow because of too deep recursion (several thousands calls deep). You could easily implement the algorithm using a loop instead.

Comment: Do you know how i could use a debugger to get this information, gdb is a powerfull, but not very user friendly program.

Comment: @Kristofer type `bt` when your program crashes and you'll see the call stack

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of any lines of code that access indices of a string that may not exist:

```
   char ch = line[0];
    uint i;
    for(i = 0; ch == line[i]; i++){

    }
    if(i != line.length()){
        line = to_string(i) + ch + count_chars(line.substr(i));
```

1. It grabs the first char from the string even if the string is empty.
2. It is only checking if i is the same as the length of the string - not if i is greater than the length of string.

Comment: I thank you for the input, this seems like good practice and worth thinking about. This was not the problem in this case thought.